# Conditional formatting on individual rows in range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want conditional formatting with color scale to easily highlight values from lowest to highest within a row. However, I have many rows.
If I go for range A1:X50, the formatting will only be based on the entire range, and not per row. But it seems really exhaustive to have to write A1:X1, A2:X2, A3:X3 etc. It beats creating individual rules per row, but it ends up being a very long string for something I would assume has some shortcuts with asterisk or similar? Tried and failed a bit with tests like (A1:X1)*(A50:X50), and so on... but no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

> it seems really exhaustive to have to write A1:X1, A2:X2, A3:X3

That will not do what you want. A color scale rule will look at *all* the values in the ranges you specify, collectively.

There are three approaches to get row-by-row heatmaps:

1. Create a bunch of color scale rules, as you mention above. There will need to be as many rules as there are rows in the data.
2. Create a bunch of regular [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules to show a heatmap per row. You will need as many rules as there are columns in the data.
3. Copy the values to another tab using a formula that replaces values with ranks for the heatmap, while *formatting* each cell to display the actual value from the source cell. That can be done with `query()` using the `format` clause. You will only need one color scale rule to format the whole range.

To try the third approach, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  highlight_, lambda(values, how_to_color, show_values, let(x,values,y,how_to_color,z,if((y="highlight")+(len(y)+rows(y)*columns(y)=1),map(x,lambda(v,match(v,x,0))),if(y="count",map(x,lambda(v,countif(x,v))),y)),makearray(rows(x),columns(x),lambda(r,c,let(v,index(x,r,c),f,index(z,r,c),if(len(v),query(f,"format Col1'"""&v&""""&if(show_values,""" (""0"")""",)&"'",0),iferror(ø))))))), 

  data, Sheet1!A1:X50, 
  ranks, byrow(data, lambda(row, 
    map(row, lambda(v, rank(v, row))) 
  )),  

  highlight_(data, ranks, ) 
)
```

Then format the range `A1:X50` in the new sheet with a color scale.